Treaps - expected time for deletion
I struggle with a specific part of the treap analysis.

Expected time for deletion
A similar analysis [to the previous section] allows us to calculate the expected number of rotations necessary to delete m from its position in the treap. The number of rotations needed is the sum of the length of the rightmost path in the left subtree of m and the length of the leftmost path in the right subtree of m. To see this, try rotating m down; if you rotate to the left (right), the length of the rightmost (leftmost) path in the left (right) subtree decreases by one and the length of the leftmost (rightmost) path in the right (left) subtree stays the same.
The Design and Analysis of Algorithms, Dexter C. Kozen, p. 69 (ISBN: 0-387-97687-6)

Why exactly the sum of the length of the rightmost and the leftmost path is the needed number of rotations? Well, it seems to me that the required number can be lesser or greater than this.
